# Deserializing Api Object with JSON.net

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

Let me explain my problem.
So I have JSON:

```
    {"num":20, "meta":[{"id":312, "identif":{"type":true,"status":false}}}]}
```

I am currently grabbing the meta id field with:

```
    var id = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<typeObj>
    (returnJSON(ApiUrl)).meta[0].id;
```

class to refrence:

```
    class typeObj
    {
        public int num {get; set; }
        public List<metatypes> meta {get; set;}
    }
    class metatypes
    {
        public int id {get; set;}
    }
```

The issue doesn't lay here though. I am trying to get the indentif status element from meta.

I have tried putting a list in metatypes like:

```
    class metatypes
    {
        public int id {get; set;}
        public List<idtypes> identif {get; set;}
    }
    class idtypes
    {
        public bool type {get; set;}
        public bool status {get; set;}
    }
```

Calling it with:

```
    var id = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<typeObj>
    (returnJSON(ApiUrl)).meta[0].identif[0].status;
```

But when I try this it returns

'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1'

Looked around and couldn't find a direct solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an incorrect json for the desired structure:

Given classes:

```
class typeObj
{
    public int num {get; set; }
    public List<metatypes> meta {get; set;}
}

class metatypes
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public List<idtypes> identif {get; set;}
}
class idtypes
{
    public bool type {get; set;}
    public bool status {get; set;}
}
```

Your json should look like (**identif must be an array**): ([.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dL98av))

```
{"num":20, "meta":[{"id":312, "identif":[{"type":true,"status":false}]}]}
```

For the json in question your classes should be like this: ([.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vmFhB8))

```
class typeObj
{
    public int num {get; set; }
    public List<metatypes> meta {get; set;}
}

class metatypes
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public idtypes identif {get; set;}
}
class idtypes
{
    public bool type {get; set;}
    public bool status {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: You are a life saver! Thank you! Can't believe that is all it took!